# Vertex transitive graphs

Tags: computational-complexity, co.combinatorics

Does having vertex transitivity make the problem of calculating independence and chromatic numbers easier?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not particularly. There is a paper by Codenotti, Gerace, Vigna "Hardness results and spectral techniques for combinatorial problems on circulant graphs" Linear Algebra Appl. 285 (1998) 123-142 which shows that computing the chromatic number of a circulant graph is NP-hard.
(The pdf is available on Codenotti's web page.) Being vertex transitive guarantees that 
a $k$-regular graph has vertex connectivity at at least $2(k+1)/3$ and that its edge
connectivity is equal to $k$. Aside from this, it is not easy to identify useful consequences of vertex transitivity.

Comment: Does the result hold if we restrict to those graphs that have exactly n(n-1)/4 edges (n is 0 or 1 mod 4) which is half the maximum (half a complete graph)?

Comment: My recollection is that it does not. (You could check the paper.)

Comment: In practice, knowing the automorphism group can help a lot, especially if the group is large, since you can remove parts of the search space equivalent to parts you have done already. In the case of very difficult problems, this can make the difference between finishing it or not.

Comment: Certainly, in a particular case transitivity can make a big difference. But I was thinking of theorems running "if $G$ is vertex transitive, then..."

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Could you elaborate? I also felt it is feasible especially if the graph is self-complementary as well.

Comment: There are not that many scvt graphs out there for a prescribed graph size!!